# Trying to add another application server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I'm trying to add another application server and running into a problem on the products config wizard.

It is indicating I am missing KB2553048 on the local server as well as the existing servers in the farm.  However it is installed and viewable on all the servers including the local one.

I've looked for solutions but have not found one that works.

Any ideas?  This is SharePoint 2010 enterprise, office web apps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had one case where if you installed patches out of order on the new server you were adding to the farm it more or less botched up the whole server and I had to re install everything on it. I can say that one thing that lead to the problem and confusion on my end was all the patches for Office Web Apps and Project Server. That being said... hopefully this isn't the case for you!

Comment: I wondered about the order and the office web apps/patches.  I'm going to uninstall web apps and see if I can get the sp side of things cleared up then work on the web apps portion.  Starting point anyway.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: For clarification... I actually had to reprovision the whole server entirely. There were always remnants of something left over that caused problems with installation / configuration after uninstalling things and trying again. Had to blow away the whole server and start fresh. Maybe I was just making a silly mistake due to frustration though. Good luck!

Comment: So uninstalling office web apps didn't help.  Made sure that all reg entries were gone.  I'm really hoping to find a way to not have to reprovision the whole server....

Comment: Could you pleas post the full error taken from the product configuration wizard?

Comment: Added image.  It's only showing two but you can get the idea.  All of the patches are installed on all servers but it is indicating that they are missing.

Comment: Ok so I used ps to hook it into the farm.  It is added but when looking in ca now all servers except the sql indicate installation required.  However when I go to look at the missing items they do in fact exist on all servers.  At a bit of a loss atm.

Comment: ... i've found some reference to a case similar to your, but I fear it would just be a wild guess. Just to see if it could apply, do you use WSUS? Have you seen any strange error on the servers? Try to have a look to this two links: [first](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/9693f5d3-a024-4a41-ae78-a6eaeb9c9529/) - [second](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/09/19/update-on-september-security-bulletin-ms11-074-and-sharepoint-2010-issues.aspx). I'm not posting this as an aswer because I don't even know if it could apply to you.

Comment: I'll take a look at let you know what I come up with.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently added an additional web front end to our farm and encountered similar issues. In our case, because all of the other servers already had SharePoint with SP1 installed, we decided to install the SharePoint version that contained SP1. Unfortunately, there were discrepancies between that version from MSDN, so we had to uninstall and add the RTM version and then SP1 separately.

Comment: Hey Sween, your answer put me on the right track.  There was a discrepancie between the RTM and the MSDN version.  And also with the CU's.  I stripped out the updates from the server install then manually installed the updates that I had saved on the other servers.  This ended up working.  Amazing how much of a pain this has been.  I appreciate all the help and suggestions from everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a simple answer but, did you try the known issues section of the KB? For KB2553048, a known issue is that a 'User Profile Synchronization' service restart is required

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553048